# Right reference on lvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

When does rvalue become right reference on lvalue?

Example is the following, and it should be solved with `std::forward`:

```
void g(int && v1, int & v2)
{
    std::cout << v1 << " " << ++v2 << std::endl;
}

template <typename F, typename T1, typename T2>
void flip(F f,T1 && t1, T2  && t2){
    g(t2, t1);
}
```

Error occurs on call like this:

```
flip(g, j, 2);
```

My problem is:
in `flip(g, j 2)`, third argument `2` is rvalue.
In function `flip`, argument `t2` is right reference on 2. When `g` is called, it seems that `t2` is right reference to **lvalue**.
In what point did rvalue, received by reference (without copying?), became lvalue?

Here is example: https://ideone.com/cJvFCg

Comment: in templates && does not necessary mean 'rvalue reference', but 'closest matching type, including rvalue ref'

Comment: I know. But: in ``flip(g, j, 2)`` third argument is rvalue of type ``int &&``. Than, t2 is deduced from ``int && && t2`` to ``int && t2``, which IS right reference. Apparently, it is not rvalue, although  it was initialized by one.

Comment: google for "c++ universal reference"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the ["if it has a name"](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html) rule saying that within code like this, if the variable has a name (in this case, your `t2`) then at that point it becomes an lvalue. (See also Scott Meyers [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do).)

To preserve the original intent of the caller, you would indeed use [perfect forwarding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward):

```
g(std::forward<T2>(t2), ...)
```

Comment: Thanx! I knew the solution, but didn't totally understand the source of problem. "If it has a name" is the key thing and it's totally clear to me, now. :)